# Aggregating numpy masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with [numpy masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) and there is a trivial operation I cannot figure out how to do it in a simple way. If I have two masked arrays, how can I get them aggregated into another array that contains only the unmasked values?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask = [0,1,1])
Out[2]:
masked_array(data = [1 -- --],
             mask = [False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [3]: np.ma.array([4, 5, 6], mask = [1,1,0])
Out[3]:
masked_array(data = [-- -- 6],
             mask = [ True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Which operation should I apply to the previous arrays if I want to get:

```
masked_array(data = [1 -- 6],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: Both arrays contain same items?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily, it's just an example with two very simple masked arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack the masks and the arrays using [`numpy.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and create a new masked array and then you can get the required output using [`numpy.prod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

```
>>> a1 = np.ma.array([1, 2, 3], mask = [0,1,1])
>>> a2 = np.ma.array([7, 8, 9], mask = [1,1,0])
>>> arr = np.ma.array(np.dstack((a1, a2)), mask=np.dstack((a1.mask, a2.mask)))
>>> np.prod(arr[0], axis=1)
masked_array(data = [1 -- 9],
             mask = [False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: The resulting array has shape 6, which is double from the shape of the initial arrays. Sorry but this doesn't respond my question.